# Configured apache2 virtual hosts show default page

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I have an Apache2 setup with the follow configuration. I'm using the placeholder domain "ilikecabbag.es" instead of the real domain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

However, when I try to access the other following VirtualHost...

```
    <Directory /var/www/ilikecabbag.es>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ilikecabbag.es/web
    ServerName ilikecabbag.es
    ServerAlias *.ilikecabbag.es
    ServerAdmin webmaster@ilikecabbag.es
    ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/ilikecabbag.es/error.log
    <Directory /var/www/ilikecabbag.es/web>
        # Clear PHP settings of this website
        <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
            SetHandler None
        </FilesMatch>
        Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        <Files ~ '.php[s3-6]{0,1}$'>
            Require all denied
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web>
        # Clear PHP settings of this website
        <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
            SetHandler None
        </FilesMatch>
        Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        <Files ~ '.php[s3-6]{0,1}$'>
            Require all denied
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    # suexec enabled
    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup web1 client1
    </IfModule>
    # add support for apache mpm_itk
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId web1 client1
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
        # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
        <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/webdav>
            <ifModule mod_security2.c>
                SecRuleRemoveById 960015
                SecRuleRemoveById 960032
            </ifModule>
            <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
                SetHandler None
            </FilesMatch>
        </Directory>
        DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp/DavLock
        # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
        # WEBDAV BEGIN
        # WEBDAV END
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

DNS is set up properly and works, I know that. ServerName, serveralias, are all set...

But all it shows is the default Ubuntu Apache2 "it works" style page.

What am I doing wrong? Using ISPConfig is that matters. Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: Not sure, but maybe try uncommenting servername for the default virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a default config that will capture all traffic on port 80.
You should check some things:

Have a look at the folder `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Is there a symbolic link to `000-default.conf`? Then this site is enabled. For instance:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 apr 16 11:58 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf`

To disable this site go to a command shell and type
`sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`.

Maybe you just need to enable the config using `sudo a2ensite yourconfig-filename.conf`.

If you want to investigate some more you should login as root (e.g. `sudo -i` ) and run some commands: ( My system name is 'Jupiter' and I'm already logged on as root using `sudo -i`). Some info is redacted to hide my websites.

```bash
root@Jupiter:~# cd /etc/apache2/
root@Jupiter:/etc/apache2# . ./envvars 
root@Jupiter:/etc/apache2# apache2 -S
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the servers fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
root@Jupiter:/etc/apache2#
```

This will guide you to the config folder of Apache2. THen the command `. ./envvars` will setup the environment to run Apache2-commands in the current shell.

The command `apache2 -S` will check your Apache2 config and show some results that might be useful.

!Notice! After changing the config of Apache2 (enabling/disabling sites or contents of config files) always reload or restart Apache2:

```bash
  sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

or on Debian

```bash
  sudo service apache2 reload
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So disabling 000-default.conf causes the "default" website, whici is redirected to despite the ilikecabbag.es virtualhost, to become a phpmyadmin login page. What. And yes, ilikecabbag.es is enabled!

Comment: Could you have a look at `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` directory? There probably is a file `phpmyadmin.conf`. Probably because you chose to let the setup-process of PhpMyAdmin install it in Apache. Or maybe you chose Lighttp as the provider?  Have you checked the `apache2 -S` output?.
I now notice the first part of your config is not within the <VirtualHost> part. Is that intentional?

Comment: It seems that even with 000-default (which is the first file in the question) and phpmyadmin disabled, Apache just "jumps" to another default site, and none of the VirtualHosts work with their servernames